403 Forbidden Error with Service Account Access to Google Search Console API
I am experiencing a persistent "403 Forbidden" error when trying to access the Google Search Console API using a service account. Despite adding the service account email with Full permissions in Google Search Console, the error persists.
Details:

Service Account Email: [your-service-account-email]

Steps Taken:

Created a new service account and key in Google Cloud Console.
Added the service account email with Full permissions in Google Search Console.
Enabled the Google Search Console API in Google Cloud Console.
Used OAuth 2.0 Playground to manually test API access.
Implemented a minimal Python script in Google Colab to test API access.



Error Message:

{ "error": { "message": "User does not have sufficient permission for site 'http://website.com'. See also: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2451999.", "code": 403, "errors": [ { "reason": "forbidden", "message": "User does not have sufficient permission for site 'http://website.com'. See also: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2451999.", "domain": "global" } ]


